# Schur complement to show determinantal inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, schur-complement

I am currently working on this problem;

> Let $A=[a_{ij}] \in M_n$ be positive definite. Partition $$ A=\begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&x\\x^* &a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$ in which $A_{11}\in M_{n-1}$. Show that $$\det(A) = (a_{nn}-x^*A_{11}^{-1}x) \det (A_{11}) \leq a_{nn} \det (A_{11})$$ with equality iff $x=0$.

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is sort of obvious. You are writing it yourself:
$a_{nn}-x^*A_{11}^{-1}x \leq a_{nn}$
because $A_{11}$ is positive definite. You know that $a_{nn}$ is non-negative. Multiply both sides with $\det(A_{11})$ and you are done.

Comment: @jens: the non-obvious part is the first equality.

Comment: Ok, but since the title of the post mentions "Schur complement", I tacitly assumed that @Almas knew about the Schur complement. In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement the extension of the $2 \times 2$ determinant formula to a $2 \times 2$ block-partitioned matrix is very well explained, and derived.

Comment: Good point. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
Y=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\-x^*A_{11}^{-1}&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ Z=\begin{bmatrix}I&-xA_{11}^{-1}\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
These are triangular matrices with diagonal equal $1$, so they have determinant equal to $1$. Then
$$
\det A=\det YAZ=\det\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&0\\0&a_{nn}-x^*A_{11}^{-1}x\end{bmatrix}=(a_{nn}-x^*A_{11}^{-1}x)\,\det A_{11}.
$$
From $\det A>0$, $\det A_{11}>0$, we deduce that $a_{nn}-x^*A_{11}^{-1}x>0$. 
For $y=A_{11}^{-1}x$, 
$$
x^*A_{11}^{-1}x=y^*A_{11}y>0,
$$
so $0<a_{nn}-x^*A_{11}^{-1}x\leq a_{nn}$. Equality implies $x^*A_{11}^{-1}x=0$, which occurs precisely when $x=0$.

Comment: How can you confirm that $\det A > 0$? Thank you!

Comment: The hypothesis is that $A$ is positive definite.